# Get 10 Digit Number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to define a function that will create a column and clean the numbers to just their ten digit area code and number. The Date frame.

```
         PNum1     
0      18888888888
1       1999999999
2  +++(112)31243134
```

I have all the individual functions and even stored them into a DataFrame and Dictionary.

```
def GetGoodNumbers(col):
    column = col.copy()
    Cleaned = column.replace('\D+', '', regex=True)
    NumberCount = Cleaned.astype(str).str.len()
    FirstNumber = Cleaned.astype(str).str[0]
    SummaryNum = {'Number':Cleaned,'First':FirstNumber,'Count':NumberCount}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=SummaryNum)
    DecentNumbers = [] 
    return df
```

returns

```
   Count First        Number
0     11     1   18888888888
1     10     3    3999999999
2     11     2   11231243134
```

How can I loop through the dataframe column and return a new column that will:
-remove all non-digits.
-get the length (which will be usually 10 or 11)
-If length is 11, return the right 10 digits.

The desired output:

```
number
1231243134
1999999999
8888888888
```

Comment: More importantly, what is your expected output? Can you indicate that in the form of an output dataframe in your question?

Comment: If 18888888888 is 11 digits, and the first number is one (the internation code), return 8888888888. If likewise, if there was a something with non-numeric characters, like +1(813)193-9183, the function would stip the characters, count the len, find the first international code, and return '8131939183'

Comment: But in your example it isn't 11 digits. So, what should the result look like? I said to please update your question... can you do it?

Comment: Edited, does that make better sense? Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Definitely did, thanks a lot. Very useful. Was able to turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove every non-digit and slice the last 10 digits.

```
df.PNum1.str.replace('\D+', '').str[-10:]

0    8888888888
1    1999999999
2    1231243134
Name: PNum1, dtype: object
```